# なにも....良かったんじゃないのか？ in this sentence

Tags: adverbs

mc misread the time and thought he was late so he ran as fast as possible to school even though he had plenty of time. His friend makes fun of his frantic behavior as he entered

> まだ本鈴まで５分あるんだから、なにもそんなになるまで全力で走らんでも、良かったんじゃないのか？

there's still 5 min before the bell rings, even if you run with all your might like that... that was a waste of effort wasn't it(?)

logically "... was a waste of effort" makes sense, but what is actually written is more like "that's good isn't it? How does なにも at the start fit in with this?

Thanks

Comment: Also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47784/5010